# how to upload multiple images with refile

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, refile

I am trying to upload multiple images but after selecting multiple images refile creating only one record. I have checked out gorails refile video from there they shown upload through adding image_id to table.
                                                              But here [refile multiple file uploads](https://github.com/refile/refile#multiple-file-uploads)

they are working with Image model.

Can anyone help me on this?

here is my code:

My model

`class Photo < ActiveRecord::Base
    acts_as_votable
  attachment :image
  has_many :users
  has_many :images
end`

My controller params

`def photo_params
      params.require(:photo).permit(:photo_title, :photo_description,:photo_caption,
       :image, :image_cache_id, :remove_image,)
end`

Photo form view

`<%= f.attachment_field :image, direct: true, multiple: true %>`

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment ( not enough reputation ) but you need to go through the refile gem README in more detail. Your models and contoller are not set up to allow multiple file uploads.

E.g you should have `(image_files: [])` in your strong parameters...

In your Photo model...
    `accepts_attachments_for :images, attachment: :file`

An image model like so....

```
  class Image < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :photo
    attachment :file
  end
```

Its all in the README.